# XMLTextReader is not reading all elements

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader

I am trying to read attributes from an XML stream.

Here is an example of the XML code

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<catalog version="1.1">
<dataset id="354" name="XXX" description="XXX" datatype="XXX" rank="XXX" saropsrank="XXX4" format="XXX" starttime="XXX" endtime="XXX" extentleft="XXX" extentbottom="XXX" extentright="XXX" extenttop="XXX" source="XXX" wmslayeridstr="XXX" confidence="XXX" directionfrom="XXX" image="XXX" />
<dataset id="354" name="XXX" description="XXX" datatype="XXX" rank="XXX" saropsrank="XXX4" format="XXX" starttime="XXX" endtime="XXX" extentleft="XXX" extentbottom="XXX" extentright="XXX" extenttop="XXX" source="XXX" wmslayeridstr="XXX" confidence="XXX" directionfrom="XXX" image="XXX" />
<dataset id="354" name="XXX" description="XXX" datatype="XXX" rank="XXX" saropsrank="XXX4" format="XXX" starttime="XXX" endtime="XXX" extentleft="XXX" extentbottom="XXX" extentright="XXX" extenttop="XXX" source="XXX" wmslayeridstr="XXX" confidence="XXX" directionfrom="XXX" image="XXX" />
</catalog>
</string>
```

The code I am using to read is as follows:

```
XmlTextReader readerXML = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);

while (readerXML.Read())
{
if (readerXML.HasAttributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(readerXML.Name + " Attribute");
    for (int i = 0; i < readerXML.AttributeCount; i++)
    {
        readerXML.MoveToAttribute(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + readerXML.Name + ", Value: " + readerXML.Value);
    }
}
readerXML.MoveToElement();
}
```

However, it only prints out

```
string Attribute
Name: xmlns, Value: http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/
```

Any idea why the first element is considered the only "element" in the XML.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
When i covert the stream to a string using the following code:

```
            WebResponse response = restWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            textBox1.Text = responseFromServer;
```

I receive this text:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
&lt;catalog version="1.1"&gt;
&lt;dataset id="354" name="XXX" description="XXX" datatype="XXX" rank="XXX" saropsrank="XXX" format="XXX" starttime="XXX" endtime="XXX" extentleft="-XXX" extentbottom="XXX" extentright="XXX" extenttop="XXX" source="XXX" wmslayeridstr="XXX" confidence="XXX" directionfrom="XXX" image="XXX" /&gt;
&lt;dataset id="354" name="XXX" description="XXX" datatype="XXX" rank="XXX" saropsrank="XXX" format="XXX" starttime="XXX" endtime="XXX" extentleft="-XXX" extentbottom="XXX" extentright="XXX" extenttop="XXX" source="XXX" wmslayeridstr="XXX" confidence="XXX" directionfrom="XXX" image="XXX" /&gt;
&lt;dataset id="354" name="XXX" description="XXX" datatype="XXX" rank="XXX" saropsrank="XXX" format="XXX" starttime="XXX" endtime="XXX" extentleft="-XXX" extentbottom="XXX" extentright="XXX" extenttop="XXX" source="XXX" wmslayeridstr="XXX" confidence="XXX" directionfrom="XXX" image="XXX" /&gt;
&lt;/catalog&gt;
</string>
```

Like the xml syntax is being converted to its entity?

Any idea why this is happening/how to fix it?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `XmlTextReader` directly. You should use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Comment: It doesn't do that for me... it's working fine for me. Your exact code, just replacing the XmlTextReader creation with a line to load from a file.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. What is 'responseStream'? I'm using File.OpenText to mimic a Stream, but that code is working as it should be using the OpenText method.

Comment: It is a stream received from a webrequest/webresponse. 

    WebResponse = webrequest.GetResponse()
    Stream responseStream = response.getResponseStream()

Comment: It looks like you have your XML embedded in some element that's being treated like a string value. My guess is that something that wants to treat the content as a string value put all the escaped entities in there for you so it didn't get processed as XML.  I don't think it was the conversion to a stream that did it, but a serialization process or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [I can never predict XMLReader behavior. Any tips on understanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125187/i-can-never-predict-xmlreader-behavior-any-tips-on-understanding)

I suggest avoiding Move methods, which will probably improve your reader's behavior.

**Edit:** However, I have tested your code and it prints all the attributes for me.